# changed tab value but not reflect in page?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm using ajax to seek a solution to dynamic update data-value in div and reflect effect in HTML.
the data-value come from the backend flask and sql DB.I know the data-value already be updated since if I refresh the page, the new data-value  be reflect in page. Is there a way to achieve this function to real-time auto reflect the effect on web page ? I don't want trigger another form submit to achieve this effect. : )

In short word, the ajax response data success, but it not update the html, so web page didn't reflect the updated value.

thank you !

```py
@app.route("/fetch_bar",methods=['POST'])
def fetch_bar():
    result = [{'hostname': 'testaa101.com', 'status': '30'}] ### example data that actually getting from DB.
    app_json = json.dumps(result)
    return jsonify(app_json)
```

```
function bar_progress(){
  $.ajax({
      url:"{{ url_for('fetch_bar') }}",
      type:"post",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success:function(response){
        var response = JSON.parse(response);
        var len = Object.keys(response).length;
        var bars = document.querySelectorAll("[id=ldBar]");
        if (len > 1)
          for( var ind = 0; ind < len; ind++){
              if (selects[index].value == response[ind].hostname)
                bars[index].setAttribute("data-value",response[ind].status);
        }}})}

  function shadow_progress() {
    bar_progress()
      setTimeout(shadow_progress, 15000);
  }
  shadow_progress();




<form id="myform" name="myform" action="{{url_for('show_select')}}" method="post">
{% for entry in entries %}
.....
<td>
      <input id="stage" type="button" class="btn-primary" onclick="readTextFile();"  name="stage" value="{{entry.stage}}" >
      <div id="ldBar" class="ldBar label-center" data-value="0" data-preset="stripe" data-aspect-ratio="none" style="width:100%;display: block;" ></div>
</td>
......
  {%endfor %}
```

Comment: Your server-side code is providing the data value in the html when the web page is requested right? This means that you need to refresh the page to get the updated value. Instead use ajax to fetch the data value from a new endpoint which serves the data value as text.

Comment: @Jackson Is there a way that page auto reflect the effect without refresh ?